# wrapper-00031607960 works on windows and linux, app is not launched on Mac, but jnlp works

Tags: java, macos, jnlp, launch, jwrapper

JWrapper seems to work perfectly for us on Windows, and Linux (we are deploying with jre1.8.0_25 on all platforms), but on mac the application unpacks ok, so far as I can tell, but it never actually runs on mac -- the installer mumbles (in its log file) about force spawn being 0 and therefore it will launch using JNI, despite that my jwrapper.xml has true.  When I run the app through JNLP, either by using our jnlp file, or a shell script that uses the Java installed into the browser to javaws the jnlp file, the app runs flawlessly.  I've pasted the url to the created app, the jnlp URL, jwrapper.xml, and the log file generated while running below:

-------------------- URL to download jwrapperified version ---------------

```
 http://www.equitieslab.com/public/download/alpha
```

--------------------- URL to jnlp --------------------

```
https://www.equitieslab.com/wiki/EquitiesLabTesting.jnlp
```

---------------------- jwrapper xml ----------------------------

```
 <JWrapper>    
    <BundleName>EquitiesLabAlpha</BundleName>
    <UpdateURL>http://equitieslab.com/public/download/alpha</UpdateURL>


    <App>
      <Name>Equities Lab Alpha</Name>
      <LogoPNG>logos/EquitiesLabSquareLogo32.png</LogoPNG>
      <MainClass>eye.page.museum.vis.VisualsForAccountPage</MainClass>
      https://www.equitieslab.com/play/alpha/ 
    </App>
    <MustFork>true</MustFork>
    <SupportedLanguages>en</SupportedLanguages>        
    <InstallType>CurrentUser</InstallType>
    <NoStripJREs>true</NoStripJREs>        
    <SplashPNG>logos/EquitiesLabSquareLogo256.png</SplashPNG>
    <BundleLogoPNG>logos/EquitiesLabSquareLogo64.png</BundleLogoPNG>   
    <JvmOptions>
     <JvmOption>-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on</JvmOption>
     <JvmOption>-Dswing.aatext=true</JvmOption>
     <JvmOption>-Xmx512m</JvmOption>
     <JvmOption>-Djavafx.macosx.embedded=true</JvmOption>
    </JvmOptions>        
    <Windows32JRE>JRE-1.8/win32/jre1.8.0_25</Windows32JRE>
    <Windows64JRE>JRE-1.8/win64/jre1.8.0_25</Windows64JRE>
    <Linux32JRE>JRE-1.8/linux/jre1.8.0_25</Linux32JRE>
    <Linux64JRE>JRE-1.8/linuxx64/jre1.8.0_25</Linux64JRE>
    <Mac64JRE>JRE-1.8/macos64/jre1.8.0_25.jre</Mac64JRE>        
    <File classpath='yes'>equitieslab.jar</File>        
<SignForWindowsAndApplet>
  <KeyStore>certs/EquitiesLabJava.p12</KeyStore>
  <KeyStoreType>PKCS12</KeyStoreType>
  <Alias>equities lab, llc's comodo ca limited id</Alias>
  <Password>TheEquitiesLabKeyStorePassword</Password>

  <JarSignerPath>../../tools/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/jarsigner</JarSignerPath>
  <JarSignerPath>../../tools/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/jarsigner</JarSignerPath>
</SignForWindowsAndApplet>    
   <SignForMac>
       <AppleRootCertificate>certs/AppleIncRootCertificate.cer</AppleRootCertificate>
       <DeveloperIdCertificate>certs/DeveloperIDCA.cer</DeveloperIdCertificate>
       <DeveloperIdP12>certs/EquitiesLabApple.p12</DeveloperIdP12>
       <DeveloperIdAlias>equities lab, llc</DeveloperIdAlias>
       <DeveloperIdPassword>TheEquitiesLabKeyStorePassword</DeveloperIdPassword>
   </SignForMac>      
 </JWrapper>
```

----------------------- log file of launch on mac -------------------------

```
+0        [JREOverride] Processing JRE Override file (JreNameOverride) 
+1        [JREOverride] JRE name overriden to Mac64JRE 
+0        [Extractor] GenericUpdater version is 00031607960 
+0        [Extractor] ONLINE wrapper: No App embedded, GU will download and run 
+0        [Extractor] Checking for a latest valid GU 
+1        [PickFolder] Folder JWrapper-JWrapper-00031607960-complete matches JWrapper  with version 31607960 
+0        [PickFolder] Set latest to 31607960 JWrapper-JWrapper-00031607960-complete 
+0        [PickFolder] Folder JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete matches Mac64JRE with version 32385489 
+1        [PickFolder] Set latest to 32385489 JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete 
+0        [PickFolder] Folder JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete.plugin matches Mac64JRE with version 32385489 
+0        [Extractor] Latest GU version exists: JWrapper-JWrapper-00031607960-complete 
+0        [Extractor] Existing JRE exists: JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete 
+1        [Extractor] Latest GUversion is newer or same as our version so will just run 
+0        [Extractor] Running without extraction now 
+0        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
+0        +++ Start: Launching 
+1        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
+0        [Extractor] Launching 'JWrapper-JWrapper-00031607960-complete' from master      
folder '/Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha' of class 0 using JRE 'Mac64JRE' 

+0        [PickFolder] Folder JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete matches Mac64JRE with version 32385489 
+1        [PickFolder] Set latest to 32385489 JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete 
+0        [PickFolder] Folder JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete.plugin matches Mac64JRE with version 32385489 
+0        [Extractor] Using private JRE JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete 
+0        File exists: /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete/bin/EquitiesLabAlpha 
+1        [Extractor] JRE LSO file is /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWApps/JRE-LastSuccessfulOptions-JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete 
+0        [Extractor] Building classpath 
+0        [Extractor] Creating launch properties 
+1        [Extractor] Checking LSO file 
+0        [Extractor] Reading /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWApps/JRE-LastSuccessfulOptions-JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete 
+0        File exists: /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWApps/JRE-LastSuccessfulOptions-JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete 
+1        [Extractor] JRE LSO file exists 
+18       [Extractor] Found 4 JVM Options 
+1        [Extractor] Launch Prop: jvm_options_0 = -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on 
+1        [Extractor] Launch Prop: jvm_options_1 = -Dswing.aatext=true 
+0        [Extractor] Launch Prop: jvm_options_2 = -Xmx512m 
+1        [Extractor] Launch Prop: jvm_options_3 = -Djavafx.macosx.embedded=true 
+0        [Extractor] Writing launch properties file 
+0        [Extractor] Writing launch properties to /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-JWrapper-00031607960-complete/JWLaunchProperties-1417548657547-19 
+1        [Extractor] Launch properties length is 1040 
+0        [Extractor] Writing to file 
+1        [Extractor] Finished writing launch properties file 
+0        [Extractor] Reading 0 extra args 
+0        [Extractor] Read JRE compatibility class jwrapper.updater.GenericUpdaterJreVerifierLaunch 
+1        [Extractor] Appending 1 command line args 
+0        [Extractor] Executable: /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete/bin/EquitiesLabAlpha 
+0        [Extractor] Argument 0: /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete/bin/EquitiesLabAlpha 
+1        [Extractor] Argument 1: -cp 
+0        [Extractor] Argument 2: /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-JWrapper-00031607960-complete/jwrapperlib/jwstandalonelaunch.jar 
+0        [Extractor] Argument 3: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on 
+0        [Extractor] Argument 4: -Dswing.aatext=true 
+0        [Extractor] Argument 5: -Xmx512m 
+0        [Extractor] Argument 6: -Djavafx.macosx.embedded=true 
+0        [Extractor] Argument 7: jwrapper.updater.GenericUpdaterLaunch 
+1        [Extractor] Argument 8: /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-JWrapper-00031607960-complete/JWLaunchProperties-1417548657547-19 
+0        [Extractor] Argument 9: -psn_0_1298749 
+0        [Extractor] This is a newer extractor... launchclass is 0 
+1        [Extractor] JRE folder is /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete 
+0        [BundleLoader] Creating jre path URL for path /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete.plugin 
+0        [BundleLoader] Created NSURL 
+18       [BundleLoader] Created Bundle 
+2        [BundleLoader] Bundle Loaded OK 
+0        [Extractor] Adjusted JRE folder is /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete.plugin/Contents/Home 
+0        [Extractor] Force spawn is 0 so attempting to launch via JNI 
+1        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
+0        +++ Start: JNI Launch 

+0        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
+0        [JNILaunch] [pid=7567] [mainThread=0] 
+4        [JNILaunch] Identified JRE path as /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-Mac64JRE-00032385489-complete.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib 
+0        [JNILaunch] ------- JNI Launch call ------- 
+0        [JNILaunch] JVM Argument 0 = -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on 
+0        [JNILaunch] JVM Argument 1 = -Dswing.aatext=true 
+0        [JNILaunch] JVM Argument 2 = -Xmx512m 
+0        [JNILaunch] JVM Argument 3 = -Djavafx.macosx.embedded=true 
+1        [JNILaunch] CP Argument 0 = /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-JWrapper-00031607960-complete/jwrapperlib/jwstandalonelaunch.jar 
+0        [JNILaunch] App Argument 0 = /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-JWrapper-00031607960-complete/JWLaunchProperties-1417548657547-19 
+0        [JNILaunch] App Argument 1 = -psn_0_1298749 
+1        [JNILaunch] JNI Option 0=-Djava.class.path=/Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-JWrapper-00031607960-complete/jwrapperlib/jwstandalonelaunch.jar 
+0        [JNILaunch] JNI Option 1=-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on 
+0        [JNILaunch] JNI Option 2=-Dswing.aatext=true 
+0        [JNILaunch] JNI Option 3=-Xmx512m 
+1        [JNILaunch] JNI Option 4=-Djavafx.macosx.embedded=true 
+216      [JNILauncher] Searching for clazz jwrapper/updater/GenericUpdaterLaunch 
+112      [JNILauncher] Searching for main method jwrapper/updater/GenericUpdaterLaunch 
+1        [JNILauncher] Set argument 0 to /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Application Support/JWrapper-EquitiesLabAlpha/JWrapper-JWrapper-00031607960-complete/JWLaunchProperties-1417548657547-19 
+0        [JNILauncher] Set argument 1 to -psn_0_1298749 
+0        [JNILauncher] About to execute static void method. 
+1        [Utils] Closing logging file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This initial launch will launch GenericUpdater which is a JWrapper class which will in turn then launch your app.  You can find the logs for GU and also for anything happening in your app in the folder described on the following page:

http://www.jwrapper.com/guide-where-your-app-is-installed-and-logs.html

they should have some more information about whats going on.

Comment: The last snippet was from the log file you mentioned...  that's why I posted it.  I couldn't make heads or tails of it, but was hoping you could.....

Comment: The plot thickens -- it ran on a new OS X 10.9.4 machine -- upgrading the machine to see if it still runs....

Comment: What version of OSX was it failing on?  Also in the folder with the logs was there only one log file?

Comment: 10.9.5, and there was one log file per launch.  The unpack log file didn't look remarkable, but when we tried it on a new mac, which started as 10.9.5 and was upgraded to 10.10.1, it had the following nice behavior:  it ran and failed as described, but then ran the second time, displaying the window correctly.  I'll accept this answer, and ask another question with the two launch issue...   Thanks!